# Compact Framework Datagrid - X in cells

Tags: datagrid, compact-framework, .net-2.0

I added few extra columns, and now these X are back but only on the first line on certain columns. By X I mean the background the cell is crossed over like a large x. I used to have this issue before and solved it by setting the alternating color to white. Nothing else has been changed aside from adding 3 extra columns to the datagrid.

Anyone knows how to get rid of them? Thanks!

PS: whoever voted it for closing should really get off the high horse and get to work

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense.  It assumes that we know some sort of history of your problem or that we read minds.  What you mean by an "X" or that it's "back".  Where was the X in the first place for it to come back from? Vacation?  The fact you are on a deadline doesn't make the question any more important or urgent to us either, so it's not relevant to the question, nor is your snide remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, CF doesn't like it when plus and minus signs are used in column.MappingName property.

Comment: it also doesn't like it when you use commas, periods in the column name.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably that the columns are set to image columns and the image source is invalid.  This has been my experience at least.  Check the source you are providing for the image of the column.

**Edit**:
Then try handling [DataError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror.aspx) as it will also present red x's for columns that have thrown errors.

Comment: Then try handling http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror.aspx as it will also present red x's for columns that have thrown errors.

Comment: I am not using DataGridView, but I thanks I will check out the possible errors.